# Read a stdclassObject to get the key and values

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

Below is the resultset of a Query.  How can I print out the column names User,UserID and place?

```
print_r($report_results);
```

$report_results is the object shown below

```
Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object ( [User] => Helton, Joshua [UserID] => 31 [place] => Dallas) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [User] => Miller, Jona [UserID] => 95 [place] => Cupertino)
        [2] => stdClass Object ( [User] => Sarah, Thomson [UserID] => 32 [place] => Las Vegas)
    )
```

Comment: Please please learn just the basics how to access an [`array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and a [`object`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)!

Answer (score 1):

Use object access notation, `->` as in

```
var_dump($stdObj->User, $stdObj->UserID, $stdObj->place);
```

What you have dumped is an array, though, so you'll have to access elements within the array:

```
var_dump($array[0]->User);
```

You probably just want to iterate over the array.

```
foreach ($user as $array) {
    var_dump($user->User, $user->UserID, $user->place);
}
```

Comment: I don't want their values..I am trying to get the column names from resultset since I am working in creating a table for displaying data which would have dynamic column names as per the query..

Comment: @Learner2011 Have you tried something to get the names?

Comment: @Learner2011 in that case it would be better for your query response to return an array with keys of the column names rather than a stdClass object

Comment: @ExplosionPills Could you please give an example as how?

Comment: @Learner2011 I would have to see the code that generates the array of objects in your question.

Comment: @ExplosionPills select user_name as User, userid as UserID, location as place from user_details.Just got the resultset from $report_results = $db->loadObjectList();

Comment: @Learner2011 right, so I need to know what `$db->loadObjectList` does

Comment: @ExplosionPills $db->loadObjectList() – returns resultset as an object. https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74374/discussion-between-learner2011-and-explosion-pills).